# npm install error after uninstalling Hyperledger-composer - Blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Hello I'm currently learning hyperledger composer but I reinstalled it and i'm installing it again. Now when I npm install, I get the error below. If anyone can help me out that would be great.

```html
➜  Dabbous-Innopay npm install

> fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 prepare /Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay
> npm run build-archives


> fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 build-archives /Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay
> gulp --gulpfile .travis/gulp.js

[16:45:08] No gulpfile found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 build-archives: `gulp --gulpfile .travis/gulp.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 build-archives script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alydabbous/.npm/_logs/2018-11-05T15_45_08_550Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 prepare: `npm run build-archives`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fabric-dev-servers@0.0.14 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alydabbous/.npm/_logs/2018-11-05T15_45_08_587Z-debug.log
```

Comment: [16:45:08] No gulpfile found

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You are Using Node 8.9 or bellow:

> node -v
>    if output is more than 8.9 then uninstall node and re-install it with 8.9 version or use nvm(Node Version Manager). Google it you can find above process easily.